Python code to assign values in a column depending on another column
I am trying to automate something, but struggling with it. It is actually my first code in Python, and I would like to order this data frame by Hotel ID (which is already done) and then create a column that says:

Look into the column "Hotel Id" and if the ID in row below is equal to the ID in current row, the write "Old", otherwise "New".

In this image we can see how the code gave the value "Old" in row whose ID=23
This is the code I am using, and it is assigning values to the incorrect rows(see picture):
def asignar_old_new(df):

    df['Old/New'] = 'New'
    for i in range(1,len(df) - 1):
        if df['Hotel Id'].iloc[i] == df['Hotel Id'].iloc[i-1]:
            df.loc[i, 'Old/New'] = 'Old'
    return df


You want to avoid iterating over dataframe rows, as that's very inefficient. IIUC, you can use numpy.where and pandas.shift to achieve what you need:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Hotel Id": [1, 1, 2]})

df["Old/New"] = np.where(df["Hotel Id"] == df["Hotel Id"].shift(-1), "Old", "New")

   Hotel Id Old/New
0         1     Old
1         1     New
2         2     New


As I understand, what you want is to iterate over the Hotel Id and label the last instance as New and previous instances as Old.
Note: After sorting values by Hotel Id, do not forget to reset indexes.
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # to reset indexes

Here is the function you need:
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(i)
    if df['Hotel Id'].iloc[i-1] == df['Hotel Id'].iloc[i]: 
        df.loc[i-1, 'Old/New'] = 'Old' # to update previous id to 'Old'
        df.loc[i, 'Old/New'] = 'New' # to update current id to 'New'

    else:
        df.loc[i, 'Old/New'] = 'New' # if ids do not match means it is very first instance

----------Testing on a synthetic Data Frame----------
Here is a synthetic DF example I used.
# Synthetic data
data = {
    'Hotel Id': [23, 23, 45, 45, 45, 67, 67, 23, 22],
    'Some Column': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'J', 'K']
}

# Creat a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Sort by 'Hotel Id'
df.sort_values(by='Hotel Id', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

for i in range(len(df)):
    print(i)
    if df['Hotel Id'].iloc[i-1] == df['Hotel Id'].iloc[i]: 
        df.loc[i-1, 'Old/New'] = 'Old'
        df.loc[i, 'Old/New'] = 'New' 

    else:
        df.loc[i, 'Old/New'] = 'New'

Output from a dummy Data Frame:
   Hotel Id        Some Column Old/New
0        22                 K     New
1        23                 A     Old
2        23                 B     Old
3        23                 J     New
4        45                 C     Old
5        45                 D     Old
6        45                 E     New
7        67                 F     Old
8        67                 G     New

